# Removing trailing zero if .00 in Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I have a Decimal field which I am printing on a VF page as follows:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!row.Opportunity.AnnualPremiumGross__c}"/>
```

The values printed are as follows:

```
123.5
123.00
50.00
1.25
```

How can I format the code so any trailing .00 are removed but values such as 1.25 are still intact?

I have tried the following, but it appears to round up the numbers which I dont want.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, 0}">
<apex:param value="{!row.Opportunity.AnnualPremiumGross__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I went through your question very quickly earlier today and responded to a different requirement. If you want only significant decimal values to show and remove trailing 0s, you have to mask your field as follows:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###.##}">
<apex:param value="{!row.Opportunity.AnnualPremiumGross__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

The # will render only significant figures